# Does go channel behavior change depending on how messages are sent to it?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Why do these 2 pieces of code execute differently?

1. Running the below code returns a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`error.

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch <- 1
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

2. Running the below code correctly returns 2 and 3 (each on its own line).

```
    ch := make(chan int)
    go buffer(ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}

func buffer(ch chan int) {
    ch <- 2
    ch <- 3
}
```

#1 executes correctly only when ch is defined as a buffered channel. Why? Why does ch in buffer() accept 2 values without complaining?

Comment: I believe this question might address this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462837/fatal-error-all-goroutines-are-asleep-deadlock-when-channel-is-not-buffered?rq=2 "Both sending and retrieving data through non-buffered channel are blocking processes.

In your code you tried to send numeric value 1 through channel ch. Since the operation is blocking, the code underneath will not be executed before the current line execution is done"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A send operation to an unbuffered channel will block until another goroutine reads from it. That's why the first piece of code deadlocks: when you send to the channel, there are no other goroutines reading from it.

In the second case, you have a goroutine sending two values to the channel, and the main goroutine is reading twice from the channel concurrent with the sends. The channel is not accepting two sends, it is doing it one by one, the first send operation is unblocked by the first read, and the second send operation is unblocked by the second read.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, since there is only one goroutine (the main goroutine) lines 3 & 4 are never reached, so its effectively:

```
ch := make(chan int)
ch <- 1               // blocks forever - as no one is reading
// fmt.Println(<-ch)
// fmt.Println(<-ch)
```

communication via channels is meant to be used across goroutines - since there is only one goroutine here it will forever block.

Buffering the channel, as you've seen, helps somewhat...

```
ch := make(chan int, 1) // buffer of one

ch <- 1               // works
ch <- 2               // blocks forever

// never reached
// fmt.Println(<-ch)
// fmt.Println(<-ch)
```

... but is somewhat contrived & not very useful.

In your second example, this is the correct pattern, having at least 2 goroutines cooperating:

```
go buffer(ch) // goroutine that writes to the channel
```

creates a dedicated writer goroutine, freeing up the main goroutine to successful read any of these writes in realtime:

```
fmt.Println(<-ch)
fmt.Println(<-ch)
```